# How to configure mpu6050 gyro sensor with stm324 in Atollic TrueStudio?

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c, stm32f4discovery, mpu6050

I am trying to build a self balancing robot as my project but, doing so has proved to be quite a challenge as I cannot find any guide or helpful content yet.

The problem is that I am using atollic TrueStudio and programming in C without using CubeMX or HAL in Keil(like most tutorials). I have managed to find some lectures regarding timers, interrupts etc but I don't know how to get data from gyro and accelero using I2C.

If there is any video tutorial or even a post about using mpu6050 with libraries, then kindly refer to me so I can learn it and use it in my robot.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Googling "mpu6050 gyro datasheet" produced plenty of hits, I can't tell you where the device would be located but that's the sort of thing you need to learn to read if you're going to program hardware at that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the data sheet and figuring out what goes where, I finally found this website which had already made a library for mpu6050 functions. I still think that you will need decent amount of understanding to make do with it but it is quite fun of you are willing to put in a little effort.

[MPU6050 Code for stm32f4](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/10/library-43-mpu-6050-6-axes-gyro-accelerometer-stm32f4/)

There are three download packages here (two at top explain I2C and one below code has mpu6050 functions)